# Insert increment value in TR in particular table - Python

Tags: python

I am very very new to Python domain

I need to insert the increment value for the <tr>.. </tr> in the particular "table 2":

*(And also Don't use any modules since Its changing the alignment and encoding and its very challenges with the input and output.)*

my Codes are below:

```
import re

TableId = 2
newtable_id = f"T{TableId}"
table = '''         <table-wrap id="T1" position="float">
                                <label>TABLE 1</label>
                                <caption>
                                        <p>Table 1.</p>
                                </caption>
                                <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>TD-1</td>
                                                <td>TD-2</td>
                                                <td>TD-3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>TD-1</td>
                                                <td>TD-2</td>
                                                <td>TD-3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>TD-1</td>
                                                <td>TD-2</td>
                                                <td>TD-3</td>
                                                </tr>

                                </table>
                        </table-wrap>
This is content

                        <table-wrap id="T2" position="float">
                                <label>TABLE 2</label>
                                <caption>
                                        <p>Table 2.</p>
                                </caption>
                                <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>TD-1</td>
                                                <td>TD-2</td>
                                                <td>TD-3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>TD-1</td>
                                                <td>TD-2</td>
                                                <td>TD-3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>TD-1</td>
                                                <td>TD-2</td>
                                                <td>TD-3</td>
                                                </tr>

                                </table>
                        </table-wrap>'''

pre, matches, posts = "", "", ""
while re.search(r'<table-wrap[^>]id="{}" float="position">((?:(?!</table-wrap>).)*)</table-wrap>'.format(newtable_id), table, re.S):
    pre = pre + re.split(r'<table-wrap[^>]id="{}" float="position">'.format(newtable_id), table)[0]
    matches = re.findall(r'<table-wrap[^>]id="{}" float="position">((?:(?!</table-wrap>).)*)</table-wrap>'.format(newtable_id), table, re.S)[0]
    posts = re.split(r'</table-wrap>', table)[1]
    str = 1
    matches = re.sub(r'<tr([^>]*)>((?:(?!</tr>).)*)</tr>', lambda trcnt: re.sub(r'<tr', '<tr{}'.format(str), re.sub(r'</tr', '</tr{}'.format(str), trcnt.group(0)), matches))
    pre = pre + matches
    table = posts
if len(pre) > 0:
        table = pre + posts

print(": {}".format(table))
```

Could someone help me on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What increment value are you talking about and where do you need to insert it?

Comment: Tables don't have any automatic increment values. Only `<ol>` does.